# self join a table with data for condition coming from second table and joining with thrid table for some more data

Tags: sql-server, join

I want to get the data from below tables based on certain conditions given right below them.

```
EmployeeSalary Table
------------------
EmpId Salary      
 1     76500      
 2     73500      
 3     90000      
 4     79000      
 5     35000

 GlobalData Table
 ------------------
 Name            Value
 NewIncrmeent    20000
 MaxIncrement    999999

 EmployeeDetails Table
 -----------------
 EmpId    Name    Department Expereince
  1       John    IT            6
  2       Kris    BPO           5
  3       Mark    Facilities    3
  4       Joe     Security      10
```

Get the list of employee details(empid,salary,name,department,expereince) whose salary + NewIncrement (which needs to be read from GlobalData table by column name "NewIncrement" and its value is 20000 for now) is greater than the given employee's salary.

For example if the input to the query is empid value of 3 then the output should be  3 records with empid's 1 , 2 ,4.

I could get the required data by useing a sql procedure but i would like to know if we can get the similar data by using a sql query. I tried joins concept but I could not get the right data.

Comment: Could you show what you tried?  Also, tag appropriately.  Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: i didn't understand the clause; "whose salary + NewIncrement " > "given employee's salary". As your example, EmpId salary is 90K + 20K = 110K. So, 110K is greater than all other salaries. Why should list just 1,2 and 4, and not 5 together? Are you missing some row at your tables between EmployeeSalary and EmployeeDetails ?

Comment: I think what they are trying to say is if everyone got the NewIncrement, return the records that would have greater than the given employee's salary.  So add 20k to all except the given employee and give me back the records that are greater than 90k.  Could use better clarification OP.

Comment: Why is salary a separate table anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM employeedetails e 
  JOIN employeesalary s 
    ON s.empid = e.empid 
  JOIN globaldata g 
    ON g.name = 'newincrmeent' 
  JOIN employeesalary x 
    ON x.empid <> s.empid 
   AND x.empid = 3 
   AND x.salary < s.salary+g.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

Also `empid = 3` has 90000 salary. 90000 + 20000 = 110000 so all the rows will be returned from `EmployeeDetails` table

```
SELECT *
FROM   EmployeeDetails ED
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   EmployeeSalary es
               WHERE  es.EmpId = ed.EmpId
                      AND es.salary < (SELECT salary
                                              + (SELECT value
                                                 FROM   globaldate
                                                 WHERE  Name = 'NewIncrmeent')
                                       FROM   EmployeeSalary es1
                                       WHERE  es1.empid = 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking in `@empID` as a variable

```
SELECT ED.EmpID
    ,ES.Salary
    ,ES.Salary + GD.NewIncrement AS ExpectedSalary
    ,ED.Name
    ,ED.Department
    ,ED.Experience
FROM EmployeeDetails ED
INNER JOIN EmployeeSalary ES
    ON ED.EmpID = ES.EmpID
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT Value AS NewIncrement
    FROM GlobalData
    WHERE Name = 'NewIncrement') GD
WHERE ES.Salary + GD.NewIncrement > (SELECT Salary FROM EmployeeSalary WHERE EmpID = @empID)
AND ED.EmpID != @empID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ed.*,es.Salary from EmployeeDetails ed 
inner join EmployeeSalary es on ed.EmpId=es.EmpId 
where es.Salary < (
        select sum(p.Salary ) from
          (
            select Salary from EmployeeSalary where EmpId =3
            union all
            select Value from GlobalData where Name  ='NewIncrmeent'
          ) as p
     );
```